# jquery finding the total height of all divs children

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

hey I have a div with 5 div's contained in it, I want to add all of their heights together,

This is the solution I ended up using based off of Jeff's answer.  Thanks for helping me out.

```
var ev_totalHeight = 0;
$("#events > div").each(function(){
    ev_totalHeight += $(this).innerHeight();
});



function events_open() {
 $("#events").animate({
"height": ev_totalHeight
  }, 450 );
}

$("#events").click(function() {
events_open();
});
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Heres a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yj8sL/2/

```
$(function(){
    var totalHeight = 0;
    $("#parent > div").each(function(){
        totalHeight += $(this).height();
    });
    alert("Total height of all divs: "+totalHeight);
});
```

As you see, there are 5 divs, with a height of 100px each, so the total height is 500px.

EDIT: Your next problem (with the animate) is that you are not telling it what unit you are using (in your case, pixels):

```
 $("#events").animate({
    "height": ev_totalHeight+"px"
 }, 450 );
```

Comment: would you mind looking at my edit?  I tried implementing what you suggested but am having trouble getting it working

Answer (score 3):

Something along these lines:

```
var height = 0;

$('#events > div').each(function(){
    height += $(this).height();
});

// apply calculated height to another element
$('#myotherdiv').height(height + 'px');
```

Comment: how would you set this up to be another div's height?

Comment: so I'm trying to do this, shouldn't this work?   $("#container").animate({
    "height": height
  }, 450 ); 
}

Answer (score 0):

Loop through them all and add the height e.g.

```
var height;
$("#events").each(function() {
    height += $(this).height();
});
```

Comment: Mine was marked down too, because it was wrong - you're missing the direct child selector: `#events > DIV`

Comment: I must admit I find that slightly annoying