# How would I code a jQuery script to sum up heights of only currently displayed divs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have divs that frequently toggle between being displayed and not displayed. These divs are also constantly changing height. They are placed within a div called Panel. Panel is always displayed and starts off with a set height of 600.

I am trying to write a jQuery script that will add up the heights of the currently displayed divs inside Panel, and to check if the heights of the displayed divs add up as greater than 600px.

If the total is greater than 600, then Panel height will be set to auto.

I can't figure out the logic of doing that.

Right now I have:

```
function CalculateHeightTotal(){
        if(
            $('#Div1').height() +
            $('#Div2').height() +
            $('#Div3').height() +
            $('#Div4').height() +
            $('#Div5').height() +
            $('#Div6').height() +
            $('#Div7').height()   
            > 600 ) { 
                      $('#Panel').css('height','auto'); 
                    }  
}
```

but the problem with that is that, because some Divs may not be displayed at the time, it shouldn't be taking those Div heights into account.

Thus, that code isn't the solution. If someone could offer insight, please do...

(sorry for the weird formatting. I'm new to jQuery.)

Comment: A similar question has been answered with solution in this [thread][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13048798/4749156

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that the wrapper div has id `parentDiv` and each inner div has a class `innerDiv`, select each visible inner div with `is(':visible')` selector and calculate it's height.

Then, add each height to a variable, let's say `h`

```
var h = 0; 
$('#parentDiv').find('.innerDiv').is(':visible').each(function() {
   h += parseFloat($(this).outerHeight());
});
```

**UPDATE**

```
function CalculateHeightTotal(){
    var h = 0; 
    $('#parentDiv').find('.innerDiv').is(':visible').each(function() {
       h += parseFloat($(this).outerHeight());
    });
    if(h > 600 ) { 
       $('#Panel').css('height','auto'); 
    }  
}
```

Comment: `outeHeight`? @kapantzak? :)

Comment: There where 2 finally ;)

Comment: Do you have tips on where in my init.js to place this? $(document).ready(function() { ?

Comment: Check my updated answer (did you try that?) -> You will have to correct the wrapper div's id and inner divs' classes

Comment: I tried it, I'm assuming it works and that I'm just making a very silly mistake preventing it from doing its thing. I'm going to keep fiddling with this =) Thank you for the help, I had no idea jQuery had those options!.